# how do I structure my site to make it SEO friendly as its single page application built with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo, single-page-application

I need to know how can I structure my site to make it SEO friendly. The site is an SPA built with AngularJS.

Comment: Somewhere https://prerender.io/ can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To build your prerender server,sipider will not analysis javascript.

```
https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary anymore to prerender your site. Google can crawl your javascript site. I'd suggest to use ui router and enable html5 mode.

- Dont expect JS generated Content to show up in the Webmasterstools
  fetch-as-crawler.
- Dont forget about the redirect (see ui router wiki page at github)
- use sitemaps for urls that are not linked from within your page (e.g. selectbox)

googles understanding is very well.